# Why does +!{}[true] output 1 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was watching this video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Trr95ij1358

And Mr Baranovskiy emphasizes that javascript developers 
should know what this evaluates to:

**+!{}[true]**

So I gave it a shot.

It outputs 1

Can anyone give me a reason for this?

Comment: I'm now wondering why this was voted down

Comment: I didn't downvote but the "trick weirdness" JavaScript questions don't generally get a lot of love around here.

Comment: lol. Ok. I thought it was a completely legitimate question. In fact I thought it was an extremely good one. Regardless, I have now been acclimated with a new unspoken cultural code held by those of the great stackoverflow community. I shall proceed to suffer in silence. :)

Comment: Use the "+" before anything and JS will try and use it as a number. It just so happens that boolean true is translated to "1". If you do +!!{}[true] it'll turn it into a '0'. The !{}[true] part is checking to see if true is a key in an empty object, which is false.. so the ! turns it into the true. *shrugs* after a while in the JS world this just becomes like another question of "why does 4 + 5 * 4 give me 24 instead of 36?"

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that clarified it.

Answer (score 2):

This gets read as

cast the negated (bool cast) value of the property accessor of {} identified by the toString value of true, into a number

So, it becomes

```
+!{}["true"]
+!undefined
+true
1
```

Comment: I don't think a property-lookup is allowed in this form. You would need to put the expression in parenthesis to reach that goal. In this notation the `{}` should not be allowed to get accessed as object literal. `{true:'foo',1:'bar'}[true]` throws an error, but `({true:'foo',1:'LOL'}[true])` returns `'foo'`

Comment: @jAndy then you would be wrong. { anywhere but at the start of a Statement signifies the start of an object literal.

Comment: @TedHopp, nope, it is 'true' - property names are always coerced to string.

Comment: @SeanKinsey: I don't think that is true either. But I do believe now that the `!` puts the statement into an *expression* and thats why the interpretor reads it as object literal and not a label.

Comment: @SeanKinsey - Oops. You're right. Deleting my comment.

Comment: It's all in the spec: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1 - step 6.

Comment: @jAndy - `{true:'foo',1:'bar'}[true]` returns `'foo'` for me. No error.

Comment: @TedHopp, are you evaling in a console? Things are differently there.

Comment: @jAndy, but it is. I've written my share of JS parsers :)

Comment: @SeanKinsey - I was using node

Comment: @SeanKinsey: well fair enough. Anyway I can't really find the section which says that a `{` anywhere but at the start of a statment indicates an object literal. Are you sure it has nothing to do with `+` and `!` which both force an expression ?

Comment: The spec doesn't explicitly say that, but it follows from where BlockStatements (which is the other kind of {}) are allowed. So, excepting constructs such as function/if/for/while/do/switch/with, the only place a BlockStatement is allowed is to begin a statement, and the only place an ObjectLiteral is allowed, is inside an expression.

Comment: @TedHopp: You're probably using the REPL, right? It won't work if that code is the content of a file.

Comment: @jAndy: Check out the NOTE for [12.4 Expression Statement](http://es5.github.com/#x12.4). I believe that's where the ambiguity is called out. The `{` at the start of a statement disallows an expression statement, like the object literal initialiser.

Comment: `{}[true] === [true]`, `null,{}[true] === undefined`, the `!` makes it read the same as the second. Additionally, `{foo:'bar'}[true] === [true]`, `{true:'bar'}[true]` gives `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`